# Многопоточность. Телеграмм бот ChatGPT на Python, aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, многопоточность, aiogram, асинхронность, threading

Я создал ChatGPT бота на aiogram, но он не многопоточен, то есть когда бот отвечает на запрос одного пользователя, то для остальных в этот момент он не работает. Сначала думал это из-за асинхронизации, голову себе чуть не сломал, перепробовал всё что знаю. В интернете об этом практически не слова.

```
#Одна из самых важных команд бота:
@dp.message_handler()
async def handle_messages(message: types.Message):
    global user_message
    global voicer_text
    global text
    global photo_text
    global user_is_replying
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Карсон печатает . . .")
    await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=user_id, action=types.ChatActions.TYPING)    
    try:

        if user_id in user_is_replying and user_is_replying[user_id]:
            await message.answer("Подождите, Карсон немного перегружен.")
            return


        if photo_text == True:
            user_message = message.text + "\n" + text
            
        elif voicer_text == True:
            user_message = text
            
        else:
            user_message = message.text
        # Проверяем длину сообщения пользователя
        if len(user_message) > max_allowed_message_length:
            await message.reply("Извините, ваше сообщение слишком большое, и я не могу на него ответить.")
            photo_text = False
            return

        if photo_text == True:
            update(user_id, 'user', message.text + "\n" + text)
            
        elif voicer_text == True:
            update(user_id, 'user', text)
            
        else:
            update(user_id, 'user', message.text)

        user_is_replying[user_id] = True
        user_messages[user_id].append({"role": "user", "content": f"Язык: ru"})
        
        response_content, response = await call_openai(message)
        #response_content = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        if len(response_content) + len(user_message) >= 15500:
                    await message.reply("Слишком большой запрос . . .\nОшибка на сервере :(")
                    photo_text = False
                    return
        if response['usage']['total_tokens'] >= 15000:
            await message.reply(
                f'В данный момент вы использовали максимум токенов в рамках контекста: {response["usage"]["total_tokens"]}, будет произведена очистка памяти'
            )
            reset_messages(user_id)

        await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=user_id, action=types.ChatActions.TYPING)
        if voicer_text == True:
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id + 2)
            await message.reply(response_content, parse_mode="markdown")
        else:
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id + 1)
            await message.reply(response_content, parse_mode="markdown")                
        photo_text = False
        voicer_text = False
        text = ""
    except openai.error.RateLimitError as ex:
        await message.answer(error)
        photo_text = False
    finally:
        user_is_replying[user_id] = False
    return False
    
# Функция для асинхронного вызова OpenAI
async def call_openai(message) -> str:
    global user_message
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    # Или какой-то другой способ получения сообщения от пользователя
    user_messages[user_id].append({"role": "user", "content": user_message})

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        messages=user_messages[user_id],
        temperature=0.8,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0.3,
        max_tokens=max_token_count,
    )

    response_content = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    return response_content, response



async def main():     
    await dp.start_polling(bot) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: Используйте `await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate` для асинхронности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо огромное пользователю gord1402! Нужно было всего лишь исправить `openai.ChatCompletion.create` на `await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate`!